# How to create SharePoint Sub-Folders programmatically?

Tags: 2013, development, custom-timer-job, subfolders

I want to refer to this question which shows how to create first-level folders:
[SharePoint Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195198/how-to-create-sharepoint-folders-programmatically)

But I also need to know how to create Sub-Folders e.g. a Sub-Folder inside a List.

Does anyone know how to create Folders inside a List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this

```
 foreach (SPListItem item in list.Folders)
                        {
                            if (item.Title == "yourfoldername")
                            {
                                SPListItem newItem = list.AddItem(item.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder);
                                newItem["Title"] = "SubFolder";
                                newItem.Update();
                            }
                        }
```

Check the full code at [Programmatically create a subfolder in SharePoint list](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/programmatically-create-a-subfolder-in-sharepoint-2010-list)

also you can add subfolder at specific folder by useing `SPFolderCollection`  as the following

```
SPFolderCollection Col = oList.RootFolder.SubFolders;
SPFolder Folder = Col[foldername];
SPListItem newFolder = oList.AddItem(Folder.Url, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, newFolderName);
```